# Is it possible to create desktop widgets using flutter windows app?

Tags: flutter, flutter-desktop, flutter-windows

**Hi, I am new to flutter desktop apps. I am trying to create desktop widgets like the image below. I searched on the internet and found nothing. Can any one help me? Thanks in advance.

[image: Text]  **

Comment: Are you asking if you can make widgets for Rainmeter using Flutter, or if you could write something like Rainmeter itself in Flutter?

Comment: @smorgan i want make new widget like rainmeter is it possible?

Comment: I can't answer because I don't know what "widget like Rainmeter" means. The things being called widgets in the image are not Rainmeter; Rainmeter is the thing that *runs* those widgets. A widget and Rainmeter are fundamentally different types of things, and I still don't know which one your question is about.

Comment: @smorgan i want to create new widget that widget always running on my desktop screen.

Comment: have you found any lead?

Comment: @Jolzal No. If you found anything please let me know.

Answer (score 1):

I didn't find any library support. In fact, you can achieve this by creating a simple desktop application in Flutter. Make the app icon invisible on the taskbar and load it in the tray icon. Disable the title bar. You can achieve as many things as you want. if you want to make it runnable on startup. put them in the "shell:startup" folder